# Figuring out a proof that $\mathbb{P}\{-\pi \leq X \leq -\pi + \delta\}=\frac{\delta}{2\pi}+\frac{\delta^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}f^{k}(-\pi+) + o(\delta^{k+1})$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

The article I am currently reading is [Intrinsic Means on the Circle: Uniqueness, Locus and Asymptotics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2141) by Hotz and Huckerman, pp. 4-5.

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable living in the unit circle and thus taking values $X \in [-\pi, \pi)$. Define the shifted r.v. $Y = X + \pi$ and denote the CDF of $Y$ by $F(\mu) = \mathbb{P}\{0\leq Y \leq \pi\} = \mathbb{P}\{-\pi \leq X \leq -\pi + \mu\}$

The authors state that [image]

and then proceed to give a proof that

[image]

What I don't understand is how $\mathbb{P}\{-\pi \leq X \leq -\pi + \delta\} = \frac{\delta}{2\pi} + \frac{\delta^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}f^{k}(-\pi+) + o(\delta^{k+1}) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\mu}{2\pi} - F(\mu) = \frac{\mu^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}f^{k}(-\pi+) + o(\delta^{k+1})$ was actually proved? To what is the Taylor expansion performed? To the function $H(\mu) = \int_0^\mu\frac{x}{2\pi} - F(x)dx$? If so, when where all all terms up to the $k+2$st term, as $H'(\mu) = \frac{\mu}{2\pi} - F(\mu), H''(\mu) = \frac{1}{2\pi} - \underbrace{F'(\mu)}_{=f(\mu)},..., H^{(k+2)} = f^{(k)}(\mu)$?